# Best Fit for Image processing (AWS, GCP, Azure etc.)

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I have an application which uploads images (png and jpeg) of at least 3 MB in size to the server and the server processes the images by creating 3 resized thumbnails of type webp.

The problem is the processing duration as well as resource consumption on the server - it takes 2 seconds to process one single photo with the 3 image outputs and the resources are almost 100% used during upload process as only one image is uploaded at a time not to "kill" the server and allow other API operations.

The server processor doesn't have integrated graphics, so when I run do the processing locally on my laptop of similar configuration but with Ryzen 7 5800U processor, it only takes 600 ms to run through the whole process  (upload time is not considered, it takes 2 seconds on the server once the image is uploaded vs 600 ms on the local machine).

My question is what is the optimal approach to server/instance selection? Are there instances with processors with integrated graphics (similar to Interl Xeon E3 Family) which could handle this kind of tasks more efficiently?

Server sizing:

vCPU (Intel Xeon 20x 3.60 GHz): 8

RAM: 32 GB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider unfortunately no, my question is rather about optimization of image processing by selecting a more proper instance as basis rather then scaling the curretly ineffiecient solution

Comment: That's pretty much the story of the cloud. You will not see anywhere near the performance of on-prem.

Comment: Have you try to use Imagemagick to process the images? I am sure it's quite fast and not so resource hungry.

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks for the tip, I need to test it